# WinHttpSetOption for HTTPS only

Tags: windows, winapi, wininet

I wanted send  request only **https**, not for http now options should I put to restrict **https** only. Not able to understand which Flags dwFlags should removed to disallow HTTP.

```
      DWORD dwFlags = SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA |
                  SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_WRONG_USAGE |
                  SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID |
                  SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID;

  if (WinHttpSetOption(hRequest,
                       WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
                       &dwFlags,
                       sizeof(dwFlags))) {

     bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
                                   WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
                                   0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0,
                                   0, 0);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

To send a request using HTTPS, you need to specify the `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE` flag when calling [`WinHttpOpenRequest()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpopenrequest):

> Uses secure transaction semantics. This translates to using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)/Transport Layer Security (TLS).

HTTPS is HTTP over SSL/TLS.